# Multiple duplicate symbols in a single static object library

Tags: c, gdb, static-libraries, nm

Why are there duplicate symbols in the same static object file? What does it mean in practice?

after running `nm /lib64/libc.so.6 | cut -d' ' -f 3 | uniq -c | sort -rn`, which looks at the symbols in the file and prints the number of times that the symbol occurs. I get the following output.

```
 59 lock
 38 buffer
 15 free_mem
 15 __elf_set___libc_subfreeres_element_free_mem__
  2 __strftime_internal
  2 startp_initialized.9864
  2 startp_initialized.11643
  2 null
  2 nbits.11331
```

update

```
00000000003c1b98 b lock
00000000003c1bb0 b lock
...
00000000003c2690 b lock
00000000003c1710 b buffer
00000000003c1718 b buffer
...
00000000003c1720 b buffer
00000000003bc768 d __elf_set___libc_subfreeres_element_free_mem__
...
00000000003bc770 d __elf_set___libc_subfreeres_element_free_mem__
00000000003bc778 d __elf_set___libc_subfreeres_element_free_mem__
...
00000000001899de r null
0000000000191e70 r null
```

update 2(possibly helpful):

```
readelf -Ws /lib64/libc.so.6 | grep .*\ buffer$
Num:    Value           Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
1277: 00000000003c1710     8 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   35 buffer
1289: 00000000003c1718     8 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   35 buffer
1293: 00000000003c1720     8 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   35 buffer
1298: 00000000003c1728     8 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   35 buffer
1319: 00000000003c1730     8 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   35 buffer
...
```

Comment: Some of the "duplicates" might be a definition (typically one only) and the other may be references to that single definition. You don't know that since you cut away that information from the `nm` output.

Comment: In particular forgot to filter all occurrences of external references (`U`) and week objects  (`w`, `W`, `v`, `V`). Those are cross-references and not duplicates.

Comment: Or maybe the symbols you are seing are `static` global symbols? So even if there are duplicates they don't clash since they are local to a single translation unit. The *storage* for these variables must be put somewhere though, typically in the global data or bss segments.

Comment: "static object library" is a weird way to call a dynamic library.

Comment: Thanks. I've been having trouble finding documentation to help discern between the difference. Do you have any helpful sources which cover this topic?

Comment: This is not an answer since I'm not entirely sure: I suspect what you're seeing is debugging symbols. I'm seeing the same thing on my system and also with `objdump -t` (objdump is much better for looking at symbol tables since it gives more information). But when looking at the actual dynamic symbol table with `objdump -T` those symbols don't appear.

Comment: @Art I just ran `objdump -t` and `objdump -T` and my output is identical to your findings. Is there more information that I should be providing to make this more clear?

Answer (score 0):

> Why are there duplicate symbols in the same static object file?

1. What you call "static object file", others call a dynamic shared object, or a shared library for short.
2. Most shared libraries are linked from multiple relocatable object files.
3. It is not uncommon to have `static` data in such object files (such data has *internal* linkage, i.e. is accessible *only* from the given object file). When you link multiple such files together into a shared library, you end up with multiple instances of such data. The names of these data items don't matter -- they don't conflict with each other by virtue of internal linkage, and it is not uncommon for the names to be the same in different source files.

Example:

```
// main.c
extern int foo();

static buffer[10];

int main()
{
  buffer[0] = 'a';
  foo();
  return buffer[0];
}

// foo.c
static buffer[5];
int foo() { buffer[0] = 'b'; return 0; }
```

When you link the two files above together, you'll have two completely separate `buffer` variables, and the return code for the program will be `0x61` (ASCII for 'a'), and *not* `0x62`, despite `foo` assigning `0x62` to `buffer[0]`.